# Loop in C++ not working again

Tags: c++, loops, double

So I've been troubleshooting this program and I've already asked questions about it before. I've taken other people's advice seriously and have applied it to my program, but it's still not working. This is the modified (albeit shortened) code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

double balance, withdraw, deposit;
std::string choice;

void withdrawmon()
{
    balance -= withdraw;
}
void depositmon()
{
    balance += deposit;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Welcome to the Bank Program." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Enter a starting balance: ";
    std::cin >> balance;
    std::cin.clear();
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Withdraw, deposit, or quit: ";
        std::getline (std::cin, choice);
        if(choice == "withdraw")
        {
            std::cout << "Enter amount to withdraw: ";
            std::cin >> withdraw;
            withdrawmon();
            std::cout << "Your current balance is $" << balance << std::endl;
        }
        else if(choice == "deposit")
        {
            std::cout << "Enter amount to deposit: ";
            std::cin >> deposit;
            depositmon();
            std::cout << "Your current balance is $" << balance << std::endl;
        }
    }
    while(choice != "quit");
    std::cout << "Thanks for using the Bank Program. Your final balance was $" << balance << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There wouldn't be a problem, and the code runs, but the output is like this: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/aocn6asjr4ofcws/Broken%20Output.PNG

As you can see the "Withdraw, deposit, or quit:" line prints itself twice whenever the loop restarts. Anyone know why? Any help is appreciated. I'm a new programmer as far as C++ goes, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Search *getline skipping* on here and you'll get a lot of answers.

Comment: Just use `std::cin.ignore();` after reading input with >> to skip the '\n' character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cin.clear()` clears the error flag and leaves the remaining contents of the line that follow the input balance in the buffer. You need can call `cin.ignore()` to handle this properly.

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe the answer was that simple. Thanks for the answer, replacing the std::cin.clear() with std::cin.ignore() fixed the problem with no hiccups. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing stream extraction operators with `getline`. In your example, `std::cin>>withdraw` got the string `"50"` when the user entered `"50\n"`. The next `getline` just gets the `"\n"`, which is why you get the prompt twice (`"\n"` != `"quit"`).

You can solve this a few ways: Either use `getline` for everything and get what you need out of each line, call `getline` after your `cin>>` to make the next read operation begin at the next line, or, as Captain Oblivious suggested, use `cin.ignore`.